# duplicate content - can't use 301 or canonical tag

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, duplicate-content, canonical-url, noindex

I recently started managing SEO for a client. I'm seeing a lot of duplicate content on their site but their custom CMS doesn't allow canonical tags, and I was told by their team that we can't use 301s.

Is there any way to clean up duplicate content without using either 301 redirects or canonical tags? Would using meta robots noindex,nofollow work in a pinch?

Comment: What about robots.txt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the meta robots tag, but I would use `NOINDEX, FOLLOW` so Google can still freely crawl through the site:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">
```

Comment: I assume you meant to use `FOLLOW` (or omit entirely) in the code snippet?

Comment: Whoops, I did indeed! Edited